# Variance of Pearson's chi-squared statistic

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, moment-generating-functions, characteristic-functions

Let $\nu=(\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_r)$, $\sum_j \nu_j=n$, be multinomially distributed with parameter vector $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_r)$ and let

$$
\chi^2 = \sum_{j=1}^r X_j^2,\qquad X_j:=\frac{(\nu_j - np_j)^2}{np_j}
$$

be Pearson's $\chi^2$-statistic. According to equation (30.1.1) of Cramér, *Mathematical Methods of Statistics* (1962 edition, p. 417),

$$
\operatorname{Var}\chi^2 = 2(r-1) + \frac1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^r \frac1{p_i} - r^2 - 2r + 2
\right).
$$

At the bottom of the subsequent page, Cramér says that this expression by an "easy calculation" from the MacLaurin expansion of the moment generating function

$$
M(t_1,\ldots,t_r) = e^{-\sum_jt_j\sqrt{np_j}}
\left(
\sum_jp_je^{t_j/\sqrt{np_j}}
\right)^n
$$

of $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_r)$. (Cramér actually works with the characteristic function $\phi(t)$ rather than the moment generating function $M(t)$, but this shouldn't make a difference for what follows.) I'm trying to do this calculation, but not finding it "easy"!

Since

$$
\operatorname{Var}\chi^2 = E[(\chi^2)^2] - E[\chi^2]^2
$$

and $E[\chi^2]=r-1$ (this part actually is easy), it suffices to compute the second moment

$$
\begin{aligned}
E[(\chi^2)^2] &= \sum_j E[X_j^4] + \sum_{j\neq k}E[X_j^2X_k^2]\\
&= \sum_j \left.\frac{\partial^4M}{\partial t_j^4}\right|_{t=0}
+ \sum_{j\neq k} \left.\frac{\partial^4M}{\partial t_j^2t_k^2}\right|_{t=0}.
\end{aligned}
$$

The complexity of the expression for $M(t)$ is blocking me from computing the necessary derivatives and simplify the resulting expression. **Can anyone suggest a way of approaching/organizing this calculation to get the desired result? Or is there a more conceptual approach that I'm overlooking?**

Comment: $2(r-1)$ is the variance of a chi-squared distribution with $r-1$ degrees of freedom.   It is easy enough to check the additional term for $r=2$ using the variance of binomial sample

Comment: You're right, the $r=2$ case is simpler, since then $\chi^2=(\nu_0 - np_0)^2/np_0p_1$ and you can express the variance of $\chi^2$ in terms of the 4th moment of the binomial random variable $\nu_0$. Is this what you had in mind, @Henry?

Comment: Yes - it was that transfer to the binomial random variable, which I might have worded better.  I have not tried, but perhaps you can get the general result with induction over the law of total variance

Answer (score 1):

The following is a calculation to get the variance of $\chi^2$-statistics, this calculation use the coefficients of the MacLaurin expansion of moment generting function to obtain the required expession.

Let
\begin{equation*}
M(\mathbf{t})=M(t_1,\cdots,t_r)=\mathsf{E}\Big[\exp\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{r}X_it_i\Big)\Big]  
\end{equation*}
be the moment generating function of $X=(X_1,\cdots,X_r)$ and
the MacLaurin expansion of $M$ be
\begin{equation*}
 M(\mathbf{t})=1+U_1(\mathbf{t})+U_2(\mathbf{t})+U_3(\mathbf{t})+U_4(\mathbf{t})+o(t^4),
 \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where $U_k(\mathbf{t})$ is the homogeneous multinomial of $t_i$s order $k$. Then
\begin{align*}
 \mathsf{E}[X_i^2]=(U_2)_{i2}, \quad \mathsf{E}[X_i^4]=(U_4)_{i4},\quad \mathsf{E}[X_i^2X_j^2]=(U_4)_{i2j2}, 
\end{align*}
where $(U_4)_{i2j2}((U_4)_{i4} \text{ resp.})$ denote the coefficient of term $t_i^2t_j^2(t_i^4 \text{ resp.})$ in $U_4(\mathbf{t})$.
Next we calculate the concrete form of (1). Since
\begin{align*}
 M(\mathbf{t})&=\mathsf{E}\Big[\exp\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{r}X_jt_j\Big)\Big]
   =\mathsf{E}\Big[\exp\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{r}\frac{\nu_j-np_j}{\sqrt{np_j}}t_j\Big)\Big]\\
   & = \Big(\sum_{j=1}^{r}p_je^{t_j/\sqrt{np_j}}\Big)^n\exp\Big(       -\sum_{j=1}^r\sqrt{np_j}t_j\Big),   \\
   \log M(\mathbf{t})& =n\log\Big[1+ \sum_{j=1}^{r}
   p_j(e^{t_j/\sqrt{np_j}}-1)\Big] -\sum_{j=1}^{r}\sqrt{np_j}t_j\\
   & = n\log\Big[1+ \sum_{j=1}^{r}p_j \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\Big(\frac{t_j}{\sqrt{np_j}}\Big)^k \Big] -\sum_{j=1}^{r}\sqrt{np_j}t_j  \\
   & = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{l-1}n}{l}\Big[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{r}\frac{p_j}{k!} \Big(\frac{t_j}{\sqrt{np_j}}\Big)^k \Big]^l
   -\sum_{j=1}^{r}\sqrt{np_j}t_j\\
   & = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{l-1}n}{l}\Big[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} S_k\Big]^l -\sum_{j=1}^{r}\sqrt{np_j}t_j, \tag{2} 
\end{align*}
where
\begin{equation*}
 S_k=\frac1{n^{k/2}k!}\sum_{j=1}^{r}p_j^{1-k/2}t_j^k. \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
In particular,
\begin{gather*}
 nS_1=\sum_{j=1}^{r}\sqrt{np_j}t_j, \qquad S_2=\frac1{2n}\sum_{j=1}^{r}t_j^2, \tag{4} \\
 S_3=\frac1{6n^{3/2}}\sum_{j=1}^{r}\frac{t_j^3}{\sqrt{p_j}},\qquad
 S_4=\frac1{24n^{2}}\sum_{j=1}^{r}\frac{t_j^4}{p_j}. \tag{5}
\end{gather*}
$S_k$ is an homogeneous multinomial of $t_j$s order $k$. Since we need 4-th order moments of
$X_j$, hence we remains lower order terms in the following expension of $\log M(\mathbf{t}) $,
\begin{align*}
  \log M(\mathbf{t})& = n\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}S_k + \sum_{l=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{l-1}n}{l}\Big[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} S_k\Big]^l \\
  & = (nS_2+ nS_3+ nS_4) +\Big(-\frac{n}{2} S_1^2 - \frac n2 S_2^2 -nS_1S_2 - nS_1S_3 \Big) \\
  & \qquad +\Big(\frac n3 S_1^3 + nS_1^2S_2\Big) - \frac{n}{4}S_1^4 + o(\mathbf{t}^4) \\
  & = T_2 + T_3 + T_4 + o(\mathbf{t}^4),  
\end{align*}
where $T_k$ is the homogeneous multinomial of $t_j$s order $k$ and
\begin{align*}
 T_2&=nS_2- \frac{n}{2} S_1^2,\\
 T_4&=nS_4-\frac{n}{2}S_2^2+nS_1^2S_2-nS_1S_3-\frac{n}{4}S_1^4. 
\end{align*}
Furthermore,
\begin{align*}
 M(\mathbf{t})&=1+(T_2+ T_3 + T_4)+\frac{1}{2}(T_2+ T_3 + T_4)^2+ o(\mathbf{t}^4)\\
 &=1+T_2+R_3+U_4+o(\mathbf{t}^4),  \tag{6}
\end{align*}
where $R_3$ is a homogeneous multinomial of $t_j$s order $3$ and
\begin{align*}
 U_4&=T_4+\frac{1}{2}T_2^2\\
 &=nS_4+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}S_2^2 -nS_1S_3
  -\frac{n(n-2)}{2}S_1^2S_2 +\frac{n(n-2)}{8}S_1^4. \tag{7}
\end{align*}
Now from (4)(5) easy to get the coefficients of $(S_k)_{j4}$. Furthermore, the $(U_4)_{j4}$
and the $\mathsf{E}X_j^4 $ could be caculated as following:
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{j=1}^{r}&\mathsf{E}X_j^4=4!\sum_{j=1}^{r}(U_4)_{j4}\\
 &=24\sum_{j=1}^r\Big[(nS_4)_{j4}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}(S_2^2)_{j4} - n(S_1S_3)_{j4} \\
 &\qquad +\Big(n-\frac{n^2}{2}\Big)(S_1^2S_2)_{j4}
  +\Big(\frac{n^2}{8}-\frac{n}{4}\Big)(S_1^4)_{j4}\Big]  \\
 &=24\sum_{j=1}^{r}\Big[\frac1{24n}\frac{1}{p_j}+\Big(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8n}\Big)
  -\frac{1}{6n}\\
 &\qquad  + \Big(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2n}\Big)p_j
 +\Big(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{4n}\Big)p_j^2\Big]\\
 &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{r}\frac{1}{p_j}+\Big(3r-\frac{7}{n}r\Big)
 +\Big(-6+\frac{12}{n}\Big)+\Big(3-\frac{6}{n}\Big)\sum_{j=1}^{r}p_j^2, 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\sum_{1\le i\ne j\le r}&\mathsf{E}[X_i^2X_j^2]=2!2!\sum_{1\le i\ne j\le r}(U_4)_{i2j2}\\
    &=4\sum_{1\le i\ne j\le r}\Big[(nS_4)_{i2j2}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}(S_2^2)_{i2j2} - n(S_1S_3)_{i2j2} \\
    &\qquad +\Big(n-\frac{n^2}{2}\Big)(S_1^2S_2)_{i2j2}
      +\Big(\frac{n^2}{8}-\frac{n}{4}\Big)(S_1^4)_{i2j2}\Big]\\
    &= \sum_{1\le i\ne j\le r} \Big[0+\Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)+0 \\
    &\qquad +\Big(-1+\frac{2}{n}\Big)(p_i+p_j) + \Big(3-\frac{6}{n}\Big)(p_i+p_j) \Big]\\
   &=(r^2-3r+2)-\frac{r^2-5r+4}{n}+\Big(3-\frac{6}{n}\Big)\Big(1-\sum_{j=1}^{r}p_j^2\Big).
\end{align*}
At last,
\begin{align*}
     \mathsf{E}[(\chi^2)^2]&=\sum_{i=1}^r\mathsf{E}[X_i^4]+\sum_{1\le i\ne j\le r} \mathsf{E}[X_i^2X_j^2]\\
     &=(r^2-1)+\frac{1}{n}\Big(\sum_{j=1}^r\frac{1}{p_j}-r^2-2r+2\Big),\\
     \mathsf{D}[\chi^2] &=\mathsf{E}[(\chi^2)^2]-(\mathsf{E}[\chi^2])^2\\
     &=2(r-1)+\frac{1}{n}\Big(\sum_{j=1}^r\frac{1}{p_j}-r^2-2r+2\Big).
\end{align*}